# TENSOR FLOW CNN MNIST EXAMPLE: HOW BATCH SIZE WORKS IN THE MODEL

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing, mnist, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

In the CNN MNIST example of tensorflow I do not understand how batch size works, when they call the model they specify the size of the bach in 100:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x={"x": train_data},
y=train_labels,
batch_size=100,
num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)
mnist_classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=20000,hooks=[logging_hook])
```

But when the model is called:

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  # Input Layer
  # Reshape X to 4-D tensor: [batch_size, width, height, channels]
  # MNIST images are 28x28 pixels, and have one color channel
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

They put -1 in batch size , I read in tensorflow tutorials and -1 they used it when they told the computer to infer that dimension What I do not understand is that before we put 100 and now because -1 do not understand how is entering the batch size to the model could you help me explaining? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

The attribute `batch_size` in the `tf.reshape()` method is completely different from the `batch_size` attribute in the `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` function.

### Batch Size in the `input_fn`

The attribute `batch_size` of the method `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` controls how much of the observation (or rows, or records) of your dataset will be trained or evaluated at a particular epoch (or time instance). So in the example provided, `batch_size = 100` indicates that 100 rows (in this case, images) from the dataset will be trained by the learning algorithm at every epoch.

### Reshaping Tensors

The method `tf.reshape` is used to change the shape of a Tensor. The method `tf.reshape` has the attributes `(tensor, shape)`. From the documentation, the `shape` attribute has a special value of `-1`, which infers the dimension of that particular axis to retain the total size.  Hence, from the example provided `[-1, 28, 28, 1]` translates to `[batch_size, row, column, channel]`. A `batch_size` of -1 implies that TensorFlow will maintain the size of the image as it is reshaped to a 1-Dimension array of 784 input features (i.e., 28 * 28) for all the images.